# Flyway Found more than one migration with version

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I've two sql files , one for oracle and one for mySql database. Path is as follows

```
  db/migration/mysql/V1_1_migration.sql
  db/migration/oracle/V1_1_migration.sql
```

while running the test , I'm getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than one migration with version 1.1
Offenders:
-> C:\code\service\db-repository\target\classes\db\migration\oracle\V1_1__migration.sql (SQL)
-> C:\code\service\db-repository\target\classes\db\migration\mysql\V1_1__migration.sql (SQL)
```

Any pointers to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The Flyway locations property needs a `{vendor}` placeholder, then [Spring Boot will work out the directory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup) from the lowercase of the database driver id (h2, mysql, oracle, etc), e.g.:

```
spring.flyway.locations=db/migration,db/migration/{vendor}
```

In the above example, vendor-agnostic scripts can go in `db/migration` and vendor-specific ones in `db/migration/oracle` etc.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 same files in \target\classes\db\migration directory. Delete one of them and restart your project.

if anything goes bad, delete your target folder and build your project again.